# for i in range(len) and regex

Tags: python, regex, list, for-loop, range

How do I generate a column for each fruit, and then add a dummy variable (or True/False) if the  column called "concatenated" mentions any of the three fruit. The column called "concatenated" could mention more than one fruit.

```
list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
for i in range(len(list)):
    df['{0}'.format(list )] = df['concatenated'].str.contains('[{0}]$'.format{list}, regex=True)
```

Comment: What is `df`? The code fails (SyntaxError) in the str.format (so I don't see the connection with the question's title). Could  you clarify your question?

Comment: df should be a pandas dataframe. @arv can you specify which output you expect (in an example list)?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['apple banana'], ['apple'], ['banana']], columns=['concatenated'])
l = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
for element in l:
    df[element] = df['concatenated'].str.contains(element, regex=True)

print(df.head())
>   concatenated   apple  banana  orange
> 0  apple banana   True    True   False
> 1         apple   True   False   False
> 2        banana  False    True   False
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this by matching on the whole word only?

Comment: sure. just replace the for-loop with
for element in l:
    df[element] = df['concatenated'] == element